# API platform + symfony (json format) doesn't return pagination metadata

Tags: json, api-platform.com

I use "symfony 4" + "Api platform" for API but I have a problem, when I try to get list data in json format the pagination metadata are missing

`totalItems
first
last
next`

Did someone have this problem & how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work by creating an event listener and inject in the response what I need